# How to get vocabulary from WordEmbeddingsModel in sparknlp

Tags: pyspark, embedding, word-embedding, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I need to create an embedding matrix from embeddings generated by WordEmbeddingsModel in sparknlp. Until now i have this code :

```
from sparknlp.annotator import *
from sparknlp.common import *
from sparknlp.base import *

# define sparknlp pipeline
document = DocumentAssembler()\
    .setInputCol("text")\
    .setOutputCol("document")

tokenizer = Tokenizer() \
    .setInputCols(["document"]) \
    .setOutputCol("token")

embeddings = WordEmbeddingsModel\
    .pretrained("w2v_cc_300d","sq")\
    .setInputCols(["document", "token"])\
    .setOutputCol("embeddings")

embeddingsFinisher = EmbeddingsFinisher()\
  .setInputCols("embeddings")\
  .setOutputCols("finished_embeddings")\
  .setOutputAsVector(True)
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[document, tokenizer, embeddings, embeddingsFinisher])
model = pipeline.fit(spark_train_df)
```

In this case, the model has an annotator WordEmbeddingsModel but this annotator doesn't have the getVocab method to fetch the vocabulary. How can I retrieve the vocabulary if the list of attributes and methods available for the model is:

```
dir(model)
['__abstractmethods__',
 '__class__',
 '__class_getitem__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__module__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__orig_bases__',
 '__parameters__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__slots__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_abc_impl',
 '_copyValues',
 '_copy_params',
 '_defaultParamMap',
 '_dummy',
 '_from_java',
 '_is_protocol',
 '_paramMap',
 '_params',
 '_randomUID',
 '_resetUid',
 '_resolveParam',
 '_set',
 '_setDefault',
 '_shouldOwn',
 '_testOwnParam',
 '_to_java',
 '_transform',
 'clear',
 'copy',
 'explainParam',
 'explainParams',
 'extractParamMap',
 'getOrDefault',
 'getParam',
 'hasDefault',
 'hasParam',
 'isDefined',
 'isSet',
 'load',
 'params',
 'read',
 'save',
 'set',
 'stages',
 'transform',
 'uid',
 'write']
```